# Where does the APU draw its intake air?

Tags: apu

In an airliner, where does the APU draw its intake air?

Is it a similar location for all airliners, or do different options exist?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The APU is usually located at the rear of the aircraft, in the tail, so the intake is generally somewhere on the side of this location. Aircraft place the inlet in different places though, and some even put the APU somewhere different. For some examples:

[image: 737 APU Inlet]
737 intake, the small [NACA inlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NACA_duct) at the bottom

[E145](http://training.deicinginnovations.com/wp-content/gallery/apu/e145-apu-intake-exhaust.jpg) (the place they don't want you to put de-icing fluid)

[B777](https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3025/3071008355_8b8546d350_z.jpg) (the scoop that opens upwards)

[A330](http://i337.photobucket.com/albums/n385/motidog/A330apu2.jpg) (a scoop on the underside of the tail)

[B727](http://i183.photobucket.com/albums/x312/CAPFlyer/727/P7120048.jpg) (inside of the wheel well)

[Here](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/tech_ops/read.main/222356) is an interesting thread including other examples.

Answer (score 1):

The specific location varies a bit with each aircraft, but in general, they are located close to the APU - so in the tail.

Many aircraft will have a door on the top of the fuselage that opens when the APU is running, while others have an inlet that is always open, like on the 737.

Answer (score 1):

The Boeing 737NG APU inlet is on the right side of the tail cone and the exhaust is 
Through the tail.